# Restar varios valores en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, proceso

tengo una consulta espero me puedan orientar, resulta que estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto pero me he topado con una pega, resulta que tengo un producto, pero este tiene varios tipos, por ejemplo una caja de cerveza, y se puede vender en unidad, six pack y caja, ahi todo bien, el problema es el inventario, ¿como hago para que esos 3 productos con cantidades separadas resten su valor en el inventario ? lo logre haciendo guardando los 3 productos con el mismo codigo y separandolos por su categoria:

```
select * from productos where codigo = '0001' and tipo ='unidad'

select * from productos where codigo = '0001' and tipo ='caja'

select * from productos where codigo = '0001' and tipo ='six'
```

y para actualizar la cantidad

```
update productos set cantidad = cantidad - 6 where codigo = '0001'
```

como veis todos comparten el mismo codigo y cuando resto en inventario, le resto a ese mismo codigo, pero me parece una mala forma, espero haberme dado a entender y de paso muchas gracias.(estoy usando c# y sql server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mundo de SQL es tan grande, que hay miles de maneras de realizar una misma tarea.

Lo primero que te aconsejo es mejorar la estructura de tus tablas, por ejemplo, puedes crear una tabla llamada ItemPresentacion que contenga la relación entre el ítem (cerveza), la presentación (caja, six, unidad), y la cantidad de unidades en esa presentación. De esta manera no tendrás que estar adivinando cuántas unidades vas a restar del inventario.

El update entonces depende de la presentación, como tú quieres. Definitivamente te recomiendo utilizar un procedimiento almacenado para tus actualizaciones. Por ejemplo:

```
create proc dbo.ActualizarInventario (@CodigoItem INT, @Presentacion nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Cantidad INT;
Set @Cantidad = (Select ip.Cantidad
                   From dbo.ItemPresentacion as ip
                  Where ip.CodigoItem = @CodigoItem
                    and ip.Presentacion = @Presentacion)
Update dbo.Inventario
   set Cantidad = Cantidad - @Cantidad
 where CodigoItem = @CodigoItem

END
```

Este es un ejemplo sencillo. Espero te ayude.

Edit: Un poco de C#.

Si deseas realizar la actualización desde c#, utilizando el procedimiento almacenado, entonces podrías utilizar el paquete SQLClient, que es el proveedor de datos de .net para SQL Server: Este es un ejemplo muy sencillo, pero que podría apuntarte al lugar correcto

```
// ... namespaces y declaración de clase
public int ActualizarInventario (Item item)
{
   var rowsAffected =0;
   using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using(var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.ActualizarInventario", con)
      {
           command.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@CodigoItem", SqlDbType.Int));
           command.Parameters["@CodigoItem"].Value=item.Codigo;
           command.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@Presentacion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
           command.Parameters["@Presentacion"].Value = item.Presentacion;
           command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           con.Open();
           rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   return rowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, lo intentare y te avisare mis resultados.

Answer (score 0):

@HenryDubon Bienvenido, Te suguiero restructurar tus tablas, segun lo que te entendi te propongo lo siguiente:

crear una tabla para registrar los tipos de presentacion de productos, esta debe estar relacionada con tu tabla producto.

> TipoPresentacion( Id, codigo_producto,   Nombre,   Cantidad)

- la tabla esta relacionada con productos ya que pueden existir
  multiples tipos por producto.
- Campo Nombre para definir el    tipo(unidad,six,caja,etc).
- El campo cantidad representa las unidades    contenidas en dicha
  presentacion ejemplo : unidad(1), six(6),    caja(20), etc.

Se debe restringir que tus datos de la tabla tipoPresentacion sean unicos

Entonces para actualizar en `sql` seria de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE
  P
  SET
  P.cantidad = P.cantidad - T.Cantidad
  FROM productos AS P
    INNER JOIN TipoPresentacion AS T ON P.codigo=T.codigo_producto
    WHERE P.codigo='0001' AND T.Nombre='six'
```